# Beamer problem - undefined control sequence enumerate - no enumerates used in presentation

Tags: beamer, compiling, undefined

I get the following error when trying to compile a presentation that compiled fine before:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> .../enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix 
                                              body end
 l.13     \end{frame}
```

The presentation was created with TexLive 2013 (where it still compiles - just tested it). Currently I am using TexLive 2017.

A MWE is the following

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{paralist}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{MWE}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item first item
        \end{itemize}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As can be seen, no enumerates are present in the example and the error persists.

Comment: Beamer heavily redefines list environments to make aware of overlays etc. Therefore beamer is not compatible with packages like enumitem, paralist etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution to the problem, which cost me some time to figure out in a more complex presentation, is removing the

```
\usepackage{paralist}
```

After removing this package the presentation compiles again.

Comment: Having the same problem a year later, finding your own answer via a google search and then thinking about telling the author he/she please should accept the correct answer, only to find out it's you, is rather priceless ;-). I can confirm again, this solves the above problem.

Comment: It solves that problem, and replaces it by lots of errors about compactitem and missing items and stuff :-/